# Какой видео кодек выбрать для максимальной совместимости?

Tags: видео, ffmpeg, mp4, кодек, avi

Есть видео, снятое на видеокамеру на магнитную касету. Для примера 1 час. Весит в формате .avi, около 2Гб, надо его пожать, до 512мб, что не сложно(и при этом ухудшения качества на глаз видно не будет). А вот в каком формате его сохранить, и какой кодек использовать, чтобы была максимальная совместимость с устроиствами: (современные телевизоры/смартфоны, ватсап/телеграм/вк). ?

Немного поясню с чем связано на вымышленном примере: есть задача сконвертировать оцифрованные видео и сохранить на подарочную флешку, для раздачи участникам, например, на встречу выпускников.
Не у каждого есть возможность/ хватает знаний скачать кодеки и запустить видео. У кого-то нет интернета. Но у всех есть возможность воткнуть флешку.. Либо в комп без интернета, либо в телевизор. Ну или к соседу прийти, в ставить в любой девайс с юсб. Нужно максимально **совместимый** вариант..

Comment: H.264 Main + AAC